# Symfony not showing PDO exceptions in production log

Tags: symfony, exception, logging, production

If my application has no connection to the database (postgres), it ends with the default error page showing the infamous error in prod-mode:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
```

In dev mode I see the error:

```
PDOException > Exception  > ConnectionException
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
```

These causes are not displayed in the logs. Neither server nor php logs. The only thing I see there is

```
172.19.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2020:09:58:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 831
```

This is my monolog configuration:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
     type: fingers_crossed
     action_level: debug
     handler: nested

  nested:
     type: stream
     path: php://stdout
     level: debug
```

Btw, I'm logging *everything* to stdout.

So, how do I get these errors to the log?

(Symfony 5.1, docker, apache2)

Comment: You have same configuration on dev and prod? Because may apache/nginx+fpm catch logs and pass to another space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `debug` verbosity is the **highest** verbosity.

The fingers crossed handler only forwards logs with a verbosity **equal to or higher than** the `action_level` to the specified handler.

So in your case it would only forward `debug` messages.

Use `action_level: error` for the fingers crossed handler and clear your cache afterwards to forward **all** logs to the `nested` handler in your case.

More information can be found in the documentation [Handlers that Modify Log Entries](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#handlers-that-modify-log-entries) of the fingers crossed handler.